# How to make the (fixed) content hide and show after rest content is scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, overlapping

```css
<style>
    div{
        height: 100%;
    }
    p{
        background-color: aqua;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <h1>hello</h1>
            <img src="image.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
             endis iusto eligendi rem solutaaborummaxime?     
        </p>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Hello, I want the fixed bottom content to be visible after all the upper contents are scrolled using html and css only if possible or by using js.

Comment: Why is the body inside the head?

Answer (score 0):

What I take from this is that you want the content to only be shown when the user has scrolled all the way down. You can simply do this by removing the `position: fixed;`, since that makes the paragraph visible at all times, even when the user is still scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript, the difference between total height and scrolling top position equal the page height indicates the page end is reached.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  let footer = document.querySelector(".footer");
  if (
    document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height - window.scrollY <
    window.innerHeight
  ) {
    footer.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    footer.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  background-color: aqua;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum
    is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model
    text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from? Contrary to
    popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the
    more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"
    (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
    The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
    from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly
    believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making
    this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from
    repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</h1>
  <img src="image.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
<p class='footer'>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. endis iusto eligendi rem solutaaborummaxime?
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `IntersectionObserver`. It will allow avoid scroll listener. If there's an element which(e.g. it is on/off the viewport) can be a trigger for hide/show, intersection will help

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <style>


    * {
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }


    /*grid background https: //stackoverflow.com/questions/3540194/how-to-make-a-grid-like-graph-paper-grid-with-just-css */

    body {
        background-size: 50px 50px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 1px, transparent 1px);
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    div.content {
        background: #aaaa;
        /* mystical numbers maybe to do with margin collapse
             https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing
             */
        margin-top: -15px
    }

    p {
        background-color: aqua;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    div.sentinel {
        height: 0px;
        background-color: #f00;
    }

    .hide {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .filler {
        height: 100px;
        background: #dddd;
        margin: 5px;
    }


    </style>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="content">
         <h1>hello</h1>
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" height="150px" width="150px">
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
         endis iusto eligendi rem solutaaborummaxime?     
      </p>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="filler"></div>
      <div class="sentinel"></div>
      <script>
         /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API */
         /* https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver*/
         /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units */
         /* https://prettier.io/playground/ */
         /* https://www.freeformatter.com/css-beautifier.html */
         /* https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html */
         /* https://goonlinetools.com/html-formatter/ */
         var intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
           (entries) => {
             entries.forEach((entry) => {
               console.log(entry);
               console.log(entry.time);
               console.log(entry.target);
               console.log(entry.isIntersecting);
               console.log(entry.intersectionRatio);
               console.log(entry.intersectionRect);
               console.log(entry.boundingClientRect);
               console.log(entry.rootBounds);
             });
             if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
               p.classList.add("hide");
             } else {
               p.classList.remove("hide");
             }
           },
           {
             root: null,
             threshold: 0,
             /* rootMargin expand bottom to make sure sentinel hits */
             rootMargin: "0px 0px 1px 0px",
           }
         );
         var mySentinel = document.querySelector("div.sentinel");
         var p = document.querySelector("p");
         intersectionObserver.observe(mySentinel);
         
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Use sentinel at bottom of body. Note: sentinel can be zero height. Increase rootMargin bottom to make sure sentinel invokes intersectionobserver callback when it transitions to anywhere in the viewport (threshold:0 and root:null).